# How To Stop Annoying "Cellular Network Not Found" Popup Prompt?

Tags: notifications, roaming

I am annoyed by this popup because if my cellular network service provider is unavailable, i don't want to use any others available. I just want to stop this popup interrupting my activity and only use my cellular network service provider.

How to turn off this popup?

Thanks.

*HTC Desire S*
*Android 2.3.3*
**Don't know my device's firmware**

Comment: I don't see such pop-ups in my Galaxy S. Can you be more specific about your device and firmware...

Comment: @SachinShekhar See my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

The popup you're referring to exists as to alert the device user that the cellular service as become unavailable. If you wish to stick to a specific network, there's nothing you can do.

Options for Mobile Networks are located at:

```
Settings → Wireless & networks → Mobile Networks
```

And there's no option to prevent the system from warning you about the lost of network connectivity.

From the above location, under "Network operators", you have an option "Select Automatically", that will allow your device to select another network without disturbing you.

<sup>*But by your question contents, you don't want this.*</sup>